# ansible template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement error

Tags: parsing, ansible, jinja2

I am probably missing something simple, but here goes.

I am new to ansible and am using the DellEMC openmanage module to gather IDRAC information. The first step is to be able to gather the info. I am having a problem parsing the output. Play book below.

'''

```
[root@<hostname> scripts]# cat test2.yml
---

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  connection: local

  collections:
    - dellemc.openmanage

  tasks:

    - name: include file
      include_vars: idrac.yml

    - name: Get Hardware Inventory
      dellemc.openmanage.idrac_system_info:
        idrac_ip: "{{ item }}"
        idrac_user: "{{idrac_user}}"
        idrac_pwd: "{{idrac_pwd}}"
      loop: "{{ idrac_ip }}"
      register: gather_system_info

    - name: Parse
      debug:
        var: "{{ item['system_info']['System'][0]['ChassisServiceTag'] }}"
      with_items: "{{ gather_system_info['results'] }}"
```

I will shorten output cause it is like thousands of lines but this is the original output I am trying to parse from. Error received was "fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got '<service_tag'. String: {{<Service_tag>}}"}

```
 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "idrac_ip": "<looped_ip>",
                        "idrac_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                        "idrac_port": 443,
                        "idrac_pwd": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                        "idrac_user": "root"
                    }
                },
                "item": "<looped_ip>",
                "msg": "Successfully fetched the system inventory details.",
                "system_info": {




"System": [
                        {
                            "AssetTag": "Not Available",
                            "BIOSReleaseDate": "07/09/2021",
                            "BIOSVersionString": "2.12.2",
                            "BaseBoardChassisSlot": "NA",
                            "BladeGeometry": "255",
                            "BoardPartNumber": "08HT8TA00",
                            "BoardSerialNumber": "CNIVC0091B0592",
                            "CMCIP": "Not Available",
                            "CPLDVersion": "1.0.2",
                            "ChassisModel": "Not Available",
                            "ChassisName": "Main System Chassis",
                            "ChassisServiceTag": "<service_tag>",
```

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of debug is incorrect.

```
    - name: Parse
      debug:
        var: "{{ item['system_info']['System'][0]['ChassisServiceTag'] }}"
```

`var` expands the expression you pass to it, and `{{ }}` expands the expression it contains. By using both together you end up templating the result of a previous templating operation, which rarely works (and is never a good idea.) This should be either:

```
    - name: Parse
      debug:
        var: item['system_info']['System'][0]['ChassisServiceTag']
```

or

```
    - name: Parse
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item['system_info']['System'][0]['ChassisServiceTag'] }}"
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay, kinda got backlogged at work. This worked for the most part, so thank you for that. However it prints the entire idrac output, then at the very bottom prints the following: "item.system_info.System.0.NodeID": "<serial_number>" How do we get it to not print all the idrac output before the actual parsing?